# How to use intents together with cogs?

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

Good day, how can I use intents together with cogs? I need to go to main.py add intents or where? I can't understand it
Here is the code itself main.py, I need intents for the command in the commands file.

Please help me, I read the documentation, but I did not find intents in cogs there

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os

TOKEN = ''

PREFIX = '!'
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = PREFIX)
client.remove_command("help")


intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True

@client.command()
async def load(ctx, extension):
    if ctx.author.id == 375240473184305164:
        client.load_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
        await ctx.send("Cogs is loaded...")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Вы не разработчик бота...")


@client.command()
async def unload(ctx, extension):
    if ctx.author.id == 375240473184305164:
        client.unload_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
        await ctx.send("Cogs is loaded...")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Вы не разработчик бота...")


@client.command()
async def reload(ctx, extension):
    if ctx.author.id == 375240473184305164:
        client.unload_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
        client.load_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
        await ctx.send("Cogs is loaded...")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Вы не разработчик бота...")


for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
    if filename.endswith(".py"):
        client.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")





client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: You add intents where you create your bot object, in your case `client`, so yes it is in the main file. In your code you can remove `client = discord.Client(intents=intents)` as it will make all the code before it not do anything.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You're defining `client` two times, get rid of the one at the end (`client = discord.Client(intents=intents)`), simply pass the intents when defining the first `client`

```py
intents = discord.Intents.all()

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = PREFIX, intents=intents)
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Remember to accpet the answer if it helped